# uri parse has private access modifier

Tags: java, string, uri

I'm trying to parse a string into uri.

here is what I'm doing : `Uri.parse("result.png")`

But it gives me error saying : parse has private modifier.

imported
`com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.Uri;`

Comment: "imported `import com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.Uri;`" why are you using that one?

Comment: what should i use ? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: If you look at the source code, you will see that this method is private as it tells you, use `java.net.URI` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Paths.get("result.png").toUri()` worked for me.

I don't know why other two aren't working.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reason to use `com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.Uri` maybe use `java.net.URI`:

```java
URI uri = URI.create("...");
```

or

```java
URI uri = new URI("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong class. You probably want [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html). You can then pass the string to its constructor.

```
import java.net.URI;

var u = new URI("result.png");
```